# How to assign cronjobs from root to another user via SSH/PuTTY (Debian)?

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, debian, putty

I have got root access to my server over SSH (putty).
Cronjobs that I have, all are listed by the root user (not good beside backup I need).

How can I check which accounts do exist, if they?
 - can I list them somehow?

If accounts do exist (more than one), how could I add cronjob by executing crontab -e to the specific user while I am logged as root user?

Thanks!

P.S. Running on Debian Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list all available users in one server, you can run the following command

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

You can then grep the output to check if the account exists

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep my_user
```

If the user does not exist, you can create it using the following commands

```
useradd my_user
passwd my_user
```

Then, you can simply migrate the existing root crontab to the my_user crontab running the following commands as root:

```
mv /var/spool/cron/root /var/spool/cron/my_user
service crond restart
```

If that still does not work, you can try running these commands afterwards. These will add your user to the list of users who do have permission to run cronjobs:

```
echo "my_user" >> /etc/cron.allow
service crond restart
```

Hope it is useful!

Comment: Is there a way to switch between accounts? ex. root -> user1

Comment: Yes, you can run "su - my_user" and you will switch to my_user